# Mapstruct explicitly map to subclass

Tags: java, inheritance, mapstruct

I have these Dtos:

```
public class AnimalDTO {
    
    Long id;
    String name;
   
}

public class DogDTO extends AnimalDTO {
    
    Long furType;
    String furColor;
    ...
}

public class FarmDTO {
    
    Long id;
    AnimalDTO mainAnimal;
    Double size;
    Integer employees;
    ...
}

public class FarmMinimalDTO {
    
    Long id;
    AnimalDTO mainAnimal;
   
}
```

If now in Mapstruct i would write something like:

```
@Mapper(config = MapperConfiguration.class) // nothing fancy in there
public abstract class FarmMapper {

       public abstract FarmMinimalDTO mapToFarmDTO(FarmDTO farmDTO);
}
```

If the `farmDTO.mainAnimal` is a `DogDTO`, mapstruct does not implicitly convert that into an `AnimalDTO`. But the main point of me putting `AnimalDTO` in the `FarmMinimalDTO`, is because I want less data in this DTO.

Can I configure that with mapstruct? Or do I have to map that individually?

Or is that `DogDTO extends AnimalDTO` already a red flag? I inherited this project, in my last projects I liked keeping my DTOs untangled although this meant duplicate code.

Comment: Can you explain better what you are looking for? What do you want to achieve? Maybe an example of the expected output can help